# How to find a 95% confidence interval by separating males/females from a dataframe column?

Tags: python, dataframe, confidence-interval

```
Give a 95% confidence interval for the average rating for male reviewers, and do the same for female
##reviewers.


group2 = bigdataframe[['rating']].groupby(bigdataframe['gender'])
group2.count()
FN  =   25740
MN  =   74260

group2.mean()
F =     3.531507
M =     3.529289

group2.std()
FS   =  1.170951
MS   =  1.109556

F - 1.96(FS/(np.sqrt(NF)))
F + 1.96(FS/(np.sqrt(NF)))

M - 1.96(MS/(np.sqrt(NM)))
M + 1.96(MS/(np.sqrt(NM)))


My error: 'float' object is not callable
```

First, I used groupby to count the reviews based on each gender. Then I was able to use the mean/std function to get the numbers I need for the formula. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: @jezrael please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this using `agg` function may be neater for your application. You can even write a custom function with which to aggregate. But here I create upper confidence interval value. When referencing columns in the agrgegate result, you need to use tuple. Apologies for my tiny sample size violating assumptions of normality)!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
sx = np.array(['M','M','M','F','F','F'])
val = np.random.normal(0,1,6)
df = pd.DataFrame({'sex':sx, 'value':val})
gp = df.groupby('sex')
result = gp.agg(['mean','std','count'])
result[('value','upper_ci')] = result[('value', 'mean')] + 1.96*np.divide(result[('value','std')], np.sqrt(result[('value','count')]))
```